# What is a good method for short text clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, text-mining

I am working on a text clustering problem. The data contains several sentences. Is there a good algorithm which reaches high accuracy on short text?

Can you provide good references?

Algorithms such as KMeans, spectral clustering does not work well for this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That mostly depends on how much "state-of-the-art" (SOTA) you want versus how deep you wish to go (pun intended...).

If you can live with just shallow word embeddings as provided by word2vec, Glove, or fastText, I think the Word Mover Distance (WMD [yes, really...]) is a nice function for measuring (short) document distances [1]. I've even seen several Python Notebooks in the past that provide "tutorials" for this distance measure, so its really easy to get going.

However, if you are more interested in SOTA, you will have to look into deep (sequence representation) learning, using some kind of recurrent network that learns a topic model from your sentences. In addition to integrating (semantic) embeddings of words, these approaches go beyond the [good, old] "bag-of-words" approach by learning topic representations using the *dependencies* of the words in the sentence[s]. For example, the Sentence Level Recurrent Topic Model (SLRTM) is a pretty interesting  deep, recurrent model based on the ideas of the more traditional LDA (by Blei et al.) or LSA (Landauer et al.), but it's only an arXiv paper (so all default "take-this-with-a-grain-of-salt warnings" about non-peer-reviewed research should apply...) [2]. None the less, the paper has many excellent pointer and references to get your research started should you want to go down this rabbit hole.

Finally, it should be clarified that I don't claim that these are the agreed upon best-performing methods for bag-of-words and sequence models, respectively. But they should get you pretty close to whatever the "best" SOTA might be, and at least should serve as a an excellent starting point.

[1] Matt J. Kusner et al. [From Word Embeddings To Document Distances.](http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v37/kusnerb15.pdf) Proceedings of the 32nd International Conference on Machine Learning, JMLR, 2015.

[2] Fei Tian et al. [SLRTM: Letting Topics Speak for Themselves.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.02038) arXiv 1604.02038, 2016.

Comment: i tried word2vec and it does not perform well for short text.

Comment: Just to be sure: My answer above does not recommend to use word2vec (alone) for short text clustering. Rather, it recommends to use WMD (over embedded vectors) and/or Deep Learning methods. (Yet, if you can train your own vectors, you get very good results with them alone, using the *Soft* Cosine Similarity, at least for a "workable prototype.")

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/RandyPen/TextCluster
This is a Cluster method specific to short text, which outperforms KMeans etc. No Need to set latent variable number.
The basic idea is to tokenize the sentence into words. Then direct to different bucket according to text component. In each bucket, calculate similarity between the sentence and the bucket. If the similarity score is higher than specific value, append this sentence into that bucket, else search for the next bucket.

[image: basic]

Comment: You need to elaborate on your answer. Don't just cite a link.